# Query in MongoDB and sort the result after changing the price value based on some rules/

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, graphql

I have situation where I want to retrieve the product list in a order(sorting) based on price. But the price on which I have to make the list sort will be a update price i.e. the price from the product collection +/- the changes that are mentioned in the rules collection.

That means:
For each product first I have to check the the whether any rule is matching with the product if yes then I have to change the price and then sort it.

So far I tried this:

```
let prodArray = db.product.find().map(function(prod) {
    var rule = db.rules.findOne({target: "product"});
    var newPrice = prod.price;
    if(!rule.children.length) {
        if(rule.check) {
            var checkValue = prod[rule.check];
            var isApplyModifier = false;
            if(rule.operator === 'equals') {
                if(checkValue == rule.value) {
                    isApplyModifier = true;
                }
            }
            if(isApplyModifier) {
                var effect = rule.modifiers[0].effects[0];
                if(effect.value.indexOf('%') !== '-1') {
                    var discountPercentage = effect.value.split('%')[0];
                    var originalPrice = prod.price;
                    newPrice = originalPrice - (originalPrice*discountPercentage)/100;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    prod.newPrice = newPrice;
    return prod;
});

return prodArray.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.newPrice-b.newPrice
});
```

But I want some solution so that I can also able to use the cursor for the pagination.

For sample, my product and rules collection will have these records:

```
db.product.insert({name: "a", price: 10});
db.product.insert({name: "b", price: 30});
db.product.insert({name: "c", price: 20});
db.product.insert({name: "d", price: 40});
db.product.insert({name: "e", price: 50});

db.rules.insert({
    "main" : true,
    "name" : "Rule no. 1",
    "active" : true,
    "children" : [],
    "type" : "and",
    "path" : null,
    "target" : "product",
    "modifiers" : [{
        _id: '001',
        name: '10% discount',
        description: 'Apply 10% discount to price',
        effects: [
            {
                field: 'price',
                operation: 'subtract',
                value: '10%'
            }
        ]
    }],
    "check" : "name",
    "operator" : "equals",
    "value" : "a"
})
```

Comment: If you post your actual collection and the output with some explanation then it would be better of answering your question

Comment: I have given the data for the product and rules collection. The rules collection data, contains the info:

    "check" : "name",
    "operator" : "equals",
    "value" : "a"
which means if the (product's name == value) then apply the modifier's effect i.e.

{
    field: 'price',
    operation: 'subtract',
    value: '10%'
}
which means the final price will be (product's price - 10% of product's price).
What I need to have a sorted product list based on that updated price.